# cell.imageView not showing an image

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimage, parse-platform

i have a tableView where i'm trying to show a image in the cell.imageView, but whatever i do it wont show an image. the subclass of the imageView is a PFImageView. i've checked that the PFFile and UIImage is not nil. What am i doing wrong?

this is what i've tried so far:

## converting to UIImage

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell! {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as PFTableViewCell
    
    cell.textLabel?.text = object.objectForKey("title") as NSString
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" // superset of OP's format
    let str = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(object.createdAt)
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = str
    var theFile:PFFile = object.objectForKey("image") as PFFile
    
    theFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                cell.imageView?.image = image
            }

        }
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Do you know that your code inside the "if error == nil" clause executes? You should add an "else" block to log the error if there is one. I'm pretty sure that you don't need the dispatch_async either; it's my understanding that the completion block runs on the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the image from a closure, which most likely is not running in the main thread. You should enclose your code in a `dispatch_async`:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    cell.imageView?.image = image
}
```

I think this is the problem, but of course I can't test it because I don't have all your sources at my disposal. Either way, even if that doesn't solve the problem, it's something you have to do because UI components must be updated from the main thread.

Comment: i've updated code i get following error on the cell.imageview row:

cannot convert the expressions type '(dispatch_queue_t, 0 -> () -> $t3)' to typr ()

Comment: That's because an optional chaining expression evaluates to a non-Void value. Since this is a single-expression closure, that will implicitly return that value from the closure, which does not expect it. You'll have to unwrap the optional.

Comment: @TomErikStøwer's comment should fix that compilation problem. However you should avoid using (code in) answers to edit your original question - that makes answers confusing for readers. My answer seems useless and open to downvote now that my suggestion is included in your question. In those case it's better to add an update section below the original question, or at least add a note stating that the original code has been modified basing on an answer.

Comment: @Antonio Didn't help me

Comment: Ok, got it `(cell.imageView?.image = image)!`

Comment: @TomErikStøwer would have never remembered that, thanks!